# Force browser to download

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using a .htaccess file to make links to JPEGs download instead of opening in the browser window.
This is what I'm using:

```
    AddType application/octet-stream .jpg
```

It's working fine in Safari and Firefox on Mac OSX but not on IE 8 on Windows.
Is there any way around this apart from writing a header in PHP which I would rather not do?

Comment: application/x-msdownload

Answer (score 5):

I think Internet Explorer does also expect `Content-Disposition: attachment` for downloads. If you have [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) available, you can do this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.jpg$">
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: +1 elegant solution, anyway the Content-disposition header is not an IE prerogative... am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found some tutorials which use another method that should work for you:

1. [Here](http://www.givegoodweb.com/post/30/forcing-a-download-with-apache-and-htaccess)
2. [and Here](http://www.timewaster.de/how-to-force-file-downloading-with-htaccess/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=...");` in PHP